# I'm unable to click the check box getting timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium

While running code for clicking the checkbox, I am observing the time out exception.
I have waited with `time.sleep(80)`, but did not work

```
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver

def filterclick(self):

   try:
  element=WebDriverWait(self.driver,80).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='select-all']")))
        element.click()
    finally:
        self.driver.close()
```

I want to check the check box, but getting time out exception

HtMl code for check box:

Comment: Where's the timeout coming from? Trying to find the element? Can you provide any stacktrace of the error and the html of the element?

Comment: See the class is `select-all`, which says that there may be multiple elements present in UI with that class. Share your HTML code.

Comment: Share the relevant HTML please.

Comment: We cannot answer your question properly without knowing the HTML representing the check box.

Answer (score 1):

Check if element is not at all visible. If that is the case then it will raise Timeout Exception.

OR you can try the following

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='select-all']")
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using element_to_be_clickable method in place of presence_of_element_located.

```
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 80)
    element = 
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='select- 
    all']")))
    element.click()
finally:
    self.driver.close()
```

Most probably this will work, if it doesn't you can try using implicit wait. I had faced a similar issue as well but it worked on using time.sleep function. Since you have already tried time.sleep(secs) try to use the implicit wait.

Here's how you can use it:

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(4)
element = find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='select-all']")
element.click()
```

I suggest using the 'wait' variable as you can reuse it somewhere else, you won't have to retype all that. For implicit wait, you can alter the wait duration as per your choice.